# Calculating Area of Raster Classes using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, field-calculator, area

I have a raster in a GRID format that was created by Image Classification. The GRID is projected in StatePlane meters, but I would like the area in square feet. I'm assuming I will need to use the Field Calculator for this, but I'm not sure what to input.

I've already created a new field int he GRID's attribute table for area. I'm running ArcGIS Desktop 10.1.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1 square metre is 10.7639104 square feet according to Google.

Therefore if the cell size is 1 each cell is 1 square metre (1 x 1), the area covered by class is:

```
Count x 10.7639104
```

if the cell size is 2 metres the area is 4 sq.m. (2 x 2) and the area covered by class is:

```
4 x Count x 10.7639104
```

If the cell size is irregular then multiply the width and height in metres:

```
( Cell Width X Cell Height ) X Count X 10.7639104
```